# Android Multitouch control

Tags: android, multi-touch, touch-event

I am trying to make a mulitouch control, but i always get errors when I remove my finger in a different sequence, as I give it to the screen.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    pointers = event.getPointerCount();
    for(int a = 0; a < event.getPointerCount(); a++) {
        expos[a] = (int) event.getX(event.getPointerId(a));
        eypos[a] = (int) event.getY(event.getPointerId(a));
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) pressed = true;
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) pressed = false;
    return true;
}
```

I think the problem is that when i remove the first finger the second one still has the id 2, but what can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the problem is that you don't get the ACTION_UP event when you release one of the fingers. The solution to this is to use ACTION_POINTER_UP. It will detect releases of any non-primary pointers and should solve the problem

Comment: But with ACTION_POINTER_UP i only know when the pointers are removed in a different sequence. How can i make the pointer 2 to pointer 1 when pointer 1 is removed?

Comment: This is done automatically. The problem id that you use getPointerID, but you don't need it. Instead of:
    expos[a] = (int) event.getX(event.getPointerId(a));
you have to write:
    expos[a] = (int) event.getX(a);